# For a set $A = \{1,3,6,14,18\}$, $x$ relates to $y$, if $y$ is divisible by $x$. Is this set reflexive, symm. antisymm. or transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For a set $A = \{1,3,6,14,18\}$, $x$ relates to $y$, if $y$ is divisible by $x$. Is this set reflexive, symm. antisymm. or transitive?

Heres what I have so far for relation $R (1,3), (3,6), (1,6) (1, 14), (6,18), (3,18)$.

Would it be all three as well as an equivalence relation?

Comment: What are your initial thoughts?

Comment: Its an equivalence relation (all three, except antisymm.)?

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be the relation you described.

$R$ **is** reflexive. This follows since $x|x$ for all $x$.

$R$ **is not** symmetric. To see this note that $1\sim 3$ since $1|3$, but $3\not| 1 $, and hence, $3\not\sim 1$.

$R$ **is** antisymmetric since $x\sim y$ and $y\sim x$ imply that $x|y$ and $y|x$. Thus, $x=\pm y$. Since $A$ consists of only positive integers, it follows that $x=y$, and therefore, $R$ is antisymmetric.

$R$ **is** transitive. To see this, suppose $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$. Then, $x|y$ and $y|z$. Whence, $x|z$, and so, $x\sim z$.

Note that, in particular, this relation is not an equivalence relation since it is not symmetric.